# How to get a list of those columns that contain any NA field?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to get a list of those columns of the pandas data frame that contain any NA field?

Once I get these columns, I want to process them in different ways. In some columns NAs will be replaced by 0. The others will be removed.

```
delay_column_names = ["",""]
df[delay_column_names].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.isnull().any()
```

will return a boolean series of if there is a null value in the column.

Comment: By the way how to filter out Trues?

Comment: What do you mean filter out Trues?  If a value is True, then it can't be null, so it'll already be filtered out from df.isnull().any().  If you're asking a separate question about filtering True values from a series: s[s != True].  If you want to filter out all rows of a dataframe where True is in any column: df[~(df == True).any(axis=1)].